# how to roate surfaceview 90?

Tags: android, service, rotation, surfaceview, egl

I'm developing a movieplayer on android 4.2 and now facing a problem that how to rotate a surfaceview with 90 degree,the surfaceview is used to render decoded video,a difference from common use is ,i add surfaceview as a system view by "windowManager.addView(mysurfacetview)" in a service,so the surfaceview have the ability to float on desktop.

whenever user want a landscape fullscreen view ,my temporary solution is start a activity that predefined LANDSCAPE in xml,this will trigger onConfigurationChanged of the service, then i using "windowManager.updateViewLayout" to trigger surfacechanged,finally resize the surfaceview to fullscreen size.

is there a better solution to rotate surfaceview ? i have used egl attatched to the surfaceview ,is it possible to rotate from egl ? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

For fullscreen try

 requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: setRequestedOrientation can only be called in activity,but i add surfaceview by windowManager.addView() from service.